# Converting GeoTIFF to USGS DEM or DTED using GDAL

Tags: gdal, dem, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, dted

I have been looking the documentation for gdal_translate and it doesn't list the -of format available options there. So I tried looking at the source and  basically ended up read the SetFromUserInput function source looks for several strings none of which has any reference to dem or dted. For reference here is the link:

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/501ca3703ff4d33badbc539ab7121f6263ff1ac3/gdal/ogr/ogrspatialreference.cpp

I see alot of examples like so:

```
gdal_translate -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY mosaic.vrt out.kmz
```

but can't find any info on the type of output formats. is there a proper documentation for this?

Comment: There is more information in a DTED than can be provided in a single input raster, also there is *very strict* dimensions so it can't really be implemented as a driver. Read https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008779 for a bit more background information. Likewise USGS DEM files have *strict dimensions*, read more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USGS_DEM; there is information on the file structure if you want to implement your own driver https://nationalmap.gov/standards/pdf/2DEM0198.PDF.

Comment: You can check the formats which are supported by your GDAL with `gdalinfo --formats`. Read also https://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html. Driver specific documentation can be found from driver manual page, for example https://www.gdal.org/frmt_dted.html and https://www.gdal.org/frmt_usgsdem.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDAL [Raster Formats](https://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) list show [USGSDEM](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_usgsdem.html) and [DTED](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_dted.html) as supporting "Copy" which means you can output a copy of an existing raster to those formats.

So try:

```
gdal_translate -of USGSDEM inputfilename outputfilename
```

and

```
gdal_translate -of DTED inputfilename outputfilename
```

Don't forget to check the format pages to see if there are any `-co` creation options you can/should specify.  In particular, note for DTED:

> **Creation Issues**
>
> The DTED driver does support creating new files, but the input data must be exactly formatted as a Level 0, 1 or 2 cell. That is the size, and bounds must be appropriate for a cell.

Comment: Your command will not generally work for DTED. Read the documents `Creation Issues The DTED driver does support creating new files, but the input data must be exactly formatted as a Level 0, 1 or 2 cell. That is the size, and bounds must be appropriate for a cell.` The command must include exactly correct `-outsize`and `-projwin` parameters. And if source data are not in WGS84 you must use gdalwarp with -te and -ts parameters instead.

Comment: I have tried `gdal_translate -of USGSDEM -a_srs WGS84 input.asc output.dem
` and I got an output with no errors and was able to open it on Qgis

Comment: update, 1 week after this I discovered that the outputted DEM file is incorrect.

Comment: @ArmenB in general this answer is correct, but like I said you need to check the format pages. Your question only asks about the documentation and I have provided that.

Comment: @Luke you are correct

Comment: @ArmenB if you're having trouble with a specific conversion, post a new question with full details (i.e `gdalinfo` output) of your tiff, the `gdal_translate` command you used and details about the incorrect result and we may be able to assist.

Comment: I definitely will once I figure how to provide it's incorrectness,  thank you @Luke